# Program crash while I try use GLFW-b in GHCi

Tags: haskell, glfw, ghci

I'm trying to write an application using **OpenGL** and **GLFW-b**, but I get into difficulties when I try to work in **GHCi**.

Here's the code:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLFW as GLFW

main = do
  GLFW.init
  GLFW.terminate
```

When I build the code using **stack build** and then execute the file, the program works correct. But if I try to execute it in ghci, **ghc.exe** crashes. How to solve this problem?

Flag **-fno-ghci-sandbox** doesn't help (https://github.com/bsl/GLFW-b/issues/53).

I am using GHC-7.10.3.